# Как исключить перезагрузку страницы при передаче параметра POST?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, form

Есть в интернет-магазине корзина разбитая на 2 вкладки. В первой пользователь вводит телефон в `input` и при нажатии на кнопку подтвердить - получает это значение в `input` поле второй вкладки с переключением на эту вкладку.

В реальном проекте при нажатии на кнопку подтвердить значение поля я получаю, вторая вкладка буквально на мгновение переключается, но срабатывает перезагрузка страницы и открывается первая вкладка.

Как исключить перезагрузку страницы или переключаться на вторую вкладку по кнопке подтвердить?

Задача упрощена, поэтому, пожалуйста, не стоит задавать вопросы для чего мне нужна такая реализация

**Код ниже:**

```js
if ($('#btn-cart').length) {
  $('#btn-cart').tab('show');
}
if ($('#transfer').length) {
  $('#transfer').click(function() {
    $('#btn-checkout').removeClass('disabled');
    $('#btn-checkout').click();
  });
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" id="btn-cart" data-toggle="tab" href="#pane-cart" role="tab">Cart</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link disabled" id="btn-checkout" data-toggle="tab" href="#pane-checkout" role="tab">Checkout</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="pane-cart" role="tabpanel">
  <form class="woocommerce-cart-form" action="<?php echo esc_url( wc_get_cart_url() ); ?>" method="post">
    <p><input type="text" name="billing_phone_visible" id="billing_phone_visible" placeholder="Номер телефона *" value=""></p>
    <p><button type="submit" id="transfer" class="button" name="sb">Подтвердить</button></p>
  </form>
  </div>
  <?php $fields = $checkout->get_checkout_fields( 'billing' );
        $fields['billing_phone']['default'] = $_POST['billing_phone_visible'];
  ?>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="pane-checkout" role="tabpanel">
    <p><input type="text" name="billing_phone" id="billing_phone" placeholder="Номер телефона *" value=""></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Где-то у Вас есть тег `form`, который Вы не включили в вопрос.

```
  $('#transfer').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#btn-checkout').removeClass('disabled');
    $('#btn-checkout').click();
  });
```

В проверках `if ($('...').length)` нет нужды.

---

Чтобы данные формы уходили на сервер:

```
$('#transfer').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#btn-checkout').removeClass('disabled');
  $('#btn-checkout').click();

  var $form = $(this).closest("form");
  $.ajax({
    method: $form.attr("method"),
    url: $form.attr("action"),
    data: $form.serialize()
  });
});
```

Comment: да, действительно, вы верно заметили, что не хватает `form` - добавил. Ваше решение позволяет переключать вкладку без перезагрузки, но теперь параметр `php` в переменную не передается.., а при исключении `e.preventDefault();` как у меня изначально - передается

Comment: видел ваше дополнение, спасибо. Но, все остается по старому - в `input` значение заносится, но в `$_POST['billing_phone_visible']` не приходит, остается пустым, тогда как с перезагрузкой все приходит..

Comment: Но, внутри
     ` success: function() {
         console.log($('#billing_phone_visible').val());
         }` значение изменилось

Comment: @Вася "но в $_POST['billing_phone_visible'] не приходит, остается пустым" - как Вы это выяснили?

Comment: вот так
`if(isset($_POST["billing_phone_visible"])) 
{
$phone_number = $_POST["billing_phone_visible"];
print_r($phone_number);
}`

Кажется, я наткнулся на источник причины, но это пока еще догадка  - сайт на `wordpress`, а там свои особые правила подключения и действия `ajax`. Напрямую, как мы видим, не работает

Comment: @Вася У Вас на странице больше одной кнопки с `id="transfer"`?

Comment: @Вася `console.log($("[id='transfer']").length);` - ?

Comment: ровно 1, в консоли 1

Comment: У меня сайт на `wordpress`, поэтому подключение и работа ajax только таким образом, который описан в статье Ajax в WordPress - https://wp-kama.ru/id_2018/ajax-v-wordpress.html
Но, т.к. в вопросе я этого не указал, то засчитываю ваш ответ как верный